# LSTM keras package incoherent output

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am mimicking the code from this [page](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/), implenting LSTM to predict time series behaviour. I use `R` so I just translated the content and adapted it to my dataset using R `keras` package.

So, here it goes, I have

`train_input` is a vector of random numbers between 8 and 21, let's say [9,10,19,17,...]. `train_output` is the shifted `train_input` vector by a one step : [10,19,17,...].

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>% layer_lstm(model,4,input_shape=c(1,1)%>% layer_dense(1)
model %>%compile(loss="mean_squared_error",optimizer="adam")
model %>% fit(train_input,train_output)
model %>% predict(test)
```

Here's I formatted the `train_input` in the expected `3D` format ,by doing

```
train_input <- array(train_input,dim=c(length(train_input),1,1))
```

Now, when I run `mod%>% predict(test)` for a test vector I get incoherent numbers between `0` and `1`, as if probabilities have been computed. Do someone have an explanation ?

Comment: you should have an additional dense layer as the output for the network, not an `LSTM`, and try using activation function `'linear'`

Comment: @djk47463 sorry I got a typo when writing the post, indeed I have this `layer_dense(1)`. Is this what you meant ?

Comment: yes can you just add it

Comment: @djk47463 that's what I did but it changes nothing

Comment: Did you normalize the input data?

Comment: @djk47463 no I didn't, does it impact so much the result ? Besides, if you normalize the data before the training and then reverse the scaling, I understand that the linear part carries without problem the scale factor, but there are some non-linearity, how does this factor is dealt with ?

Comment: It can, think about the input gates activation of lstm is a sigmoid, so the activation is on a 0-1 scale. So in your sample a 19 will always carry more weight on the output of the network then say a 1, in the blog you posted he does scaling too. Normalizing is pretty standard for ANNs.